# What is the advantage of making a column VARCHAR (somenumber) as opposed to NVARCHAR?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

In my development I always make my `VARCHAR` columns have a character length, e.g. `summary VARCHAR (250)` because I think *"250 characters should be enough to hold the summary."* Then I end up lengthening it later when a content manager tells me they're getting an error when they write the summary. **Very rarely do I have a situation where I know for sure how long the text in the columns should be exactly or at most.** So it seems like I should just use `NVARCHAR`, which I assume has as its underlying datastructure a dynamic character array as opposed to a fixed-size character array. Or is there some other reason why I should be using `VARCHAR (somenumber)` ?????

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  They store strings differently.  But, in either case, your assumption is incorrect.  With a length of 255, both `nvarchar()` and `varchar()` support 255 characters.  The difference is what is considered a character.  If you want a longer field, use something like `varchar(max)` or `varchar(8000)` in SQL Server or `text` or `varchar(<bigger number>)` in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

NVARCHAR does not mean at all what you think it does. The `N` just means to use unicode characters instead of ascii (which, by the way, is probably a good idea for summary fields). NVARCHAR columns still require a length.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken about the NVARCHAR. NVARCHAR is used for Unicode strings. You can also specify a max length for NVARCHAR. NVARCHARs take up more space than a VARCHAR but have a wider range of characters and symbols that can be used.

In SQL Server, if you don't specify the max length, it defaults to 1. So just declaring it as NVARCHAR is the same as NVARCHAR(1). The same goes for VARCHAR. Also, the length is not a fixed-size for VARCHAR and NVARCHAR, it only specifies the max size.

You tagged this question both MySQL and SQL Server; I don't know what it defaults to in MySQL.

You could go with VARCHAR(MAX) but be careful with that. Using MAX changes the way the SQL Server database engine stores the data. It stores it like a TEXT field which doesn't have all the functionality of a VARCHAR field. Use VARCHAR(8000) instead.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "does not have all the functionality".  The main difference is the storage location.  IN-ROW, ROW-OVERFLOW and LOB pages.  See Kalen for details.  http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2011/06/26/where-are-lobs-stored.aspx

Comment: You can't put a regular index on a VARCHAR(MAX) field.

Comment: If you have a large VARCHAR(X) field with large X anyways, you want a full text index.  Any search for patterns in the middle results in a full table scan.  It is not a SARGABLE column.  In short, your statement is misleading!

Answer (score 0):

**Is this for SQL Server?**

The main question is whether or not the application needs to support cultural information such as various languages.

If you need such support, NVARCHAR() stores unicode characters and supports all types of languages.  Remember, every character requires two bytes.

If the application is internal for just a US company, VARCHAR() will save you one byte per character.

If I remember from the SQL Server internals book, a VARCHAR(25) with the string "HELLO WORLD" is 11 characters long with an overhead of two bytes.

So let's review.

```
DECLARE @A CHAR(11) = "HELLO WORLD"     -- Takes 11 characters to store 
DECLARE @B VARCHAR(11) = "HELLO WORLD"  -- Takes 13 characters to store
DECLARE @C NVARCHAR(11) = "HELLO WORLD"  -- Takes 24 characters to store
```

Good luck with your text.

John Miner
The Crafty DBA